# Restricting function to object type

Tags: flowtype

I have a function which iterates over an object's properties, like this:

```
function somef(obj) {
    for (const prop in obj) {}
}
```

This is reported as a possible string by Flowtype:

```
Cannot iterate using a `for...in` statement because string [1] is not an object, null, or undefined. [invalid-in-rhs]

54|     for (const prop in obj) {}
                           ^^^

References:

54|     for (const prop in obj) {}
                   ^^^^ [1]
```

I tried typing `obj` as `any`, and this checks, but then it allows passing in a `string` to `somef()`, which I understand as `string` being an `any`:

```
function somef(obj:any) {
    for (const prop in obj) {}    // Would fail at runtime
}
somf("mystring)  // Checks
```

Is it possible to restrict `somef` to only accept bracket objects `obj` of the form `{}` on which I can call: `for (prop in obj) {}` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not given any explicit type def to the function so it implicitly defines types based on the code around it, given it's being called with a string, it would assume `obj` is a string and it can't be looped. It throws an error correctly, just not in the place you expect because of this implicitly typed def.

---

If you know the exact structure of the object, you can type as

```
function somef(obj: { a: string, b: string }) {
    for (const prop in obj) {}
}
```

But if it's more unknown I recommend indexer object,

```
function somef(obj: { [key: string]: any }) {
    for (const prop in obj) {}    // Would fail at runtime
}
```

docs: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/

[try](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKbABRwEYBWAXIgN6IDaA1hgJ4nJQBOMYA5gLokCGYtiAXwCUZAFCIJiYHCaJsEBI0QAHJnGWJWifARGkBkxAHojiAOpwQAGwAmU7jCuJuURE3CxMogaNGpMOABEaLSMLOyBQgDcxqYAwgAWGBBUyKJAA) example